# How to call OneToOneField reverse relationship in template (django)?

Tags: python, django, model, django-templates

I have these models in my models.py 
`User Model`

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.email)
```

`UserInfo Model`

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    """User's Info"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="parent_user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_image_file_path)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.user)
```

**My-template** 
In my template i am passing some `filtered User Profiles`(let's say filtering by age, if `age > 25` ) now i need to show the name of the user(`first_name`) as well but i don't know how to call a OneToOnefield reversely. Help is really appreciated :).

```
  {% for p in profiles %}
      <div class="profile-container" style="position: relative">
          <div class ="left-div"> 
              <div class="mySlides fade">
                  <img src="media/{{p.image}}" style="width:100%" id="user-media-img">

                  <div class="text">
                      User First Name is : {{`What to type here?`}} 
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="right-div">
              <div class="details">
                  <h1>BIO</h1>
                  <p>{{p.bio}}</p>
                  <h1>Age:</h1>
                  <p>{{p.age}}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

EDIT :
My `views.py`: 
I am passing a list named profiles which have filtered profiles based on 2-3 different type of filters so the code will be too much to paste here with all the references,
I am pasting short version here:

```
start =18
end=25
 matching = UserInfo.objects.filter(
        age__gte=start, age__lte=end
    ).values()

    for z in matching:
        if z['user_id'] not in rec_ids:
            profiles.append(z)
    print('profiles====', profiles)

 context = {
        'profiles' : profiles,
    }

    return render(request, 'home/news.html', context)
```

Pasting the output here

```
profiles==== [{'id': 18, 'user_id': 8, 'image': 'uploads/user/image/9d096190-73a0-4885-b4cd-ef6c7229b9eb.png', 'age': 23, 'bio': 'cool'}..etc]
```

Thanks :)

Comment: {{ p.user.first_name }}

Comment: @khadimhusen its not working!

Comment: Can you include your view to show what `profiles` is defined as?

Comment: Agreed, please add the view to your question. Also, it shouldn't really be needed in this case since this is relatively simple, but you can always run the shell `python manage.py shell`, import your User or UserInfo model (same as you would for a view), get an instance (e.g. u = User.objects.get(pk=1)), and then use `dir(u)` to see all attributes of that object.

Comment: @markwalker_, please check the edit... also thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @RahulNegi try removing your call to `values()` and maybe rewriting your filtering to include this logic: `not in rec_ids` (you should be able to use `.exclude()`

Comment: @getup8 as far as i know excludes is used to exclude within a model object right?, `rec_ids` has values from another model. correct me if i'm wrong!.

Comment: @RahulNegi try `UserInfo.objects.filter(age__gte=start, age__lte=end).exclude(user_id__in=rec_ids)`

Comment: @getup8 yeah removing values worked! thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @khadim hussen wrote in the comment you should use the following syntax:

```
p.user.first_name
```

Where `p` is your `UserInfo` model and `p.user` is the reference to the OneToOne realationship.

Note that when you don't have a related user with p -> user the value you will return is `None`.

If you want to show different info than `None` in your template just can do the following validation:

```
{% if p.user is not None %}
    {{p.user}}
{% else %}
    Without User
{% endif %}
```

But in your views yo will get a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExists` to ensure in your views that the relationship exists you can make the following validation:

```
p = UserInfo.objects.first()
if hasattr(p, 'user'):
   user = p.user
```

Other thing that is important is when you have a related_name property as in your example:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="parent_user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So in this case you need to refer to the `user` property with the `related_name`.

In a more concrete way you have to do as following:

```
{{ p.parent_user.first_name }}
```

One important thing is that if you ar using `queryset.filter(...).values()` so if you want to load values from other model you can use the following:

````
queryset.filter(...).values('image','age','bio','user','parent_user__first_name',...)
``
And in your template:
```python
{% p.parent_user__first_name %}
````

That's it.

Comment: the validation is working fine, but the template is still not loading the first_name, also check the edited version thanks.

Comment: @RahulNegi check the information updated. I think you need to use the related_name to access to the onetoone relationship.

Comment: i have tried {{ p.parent_user.first_name }} also but not working! :'( , it is still a none value.

Comment: Then if is `None` it means that there is not a user associated with that instance. Are you sure you have a related value in there?

Comment: actually, the validation method `p = UserInfo.objects.first()` is working fine but its not working for `p = profiles.objects.first()` clearly because profiles is just a list, how to achieve that in here?

Comment: The problem is because you are using `values`, checkout the updated response, you have to direct your attention in the values and add your related field there.

Comment: Yeah true i got it i tried without using `values()`  its working fine, but values('parent_user__first_name') is throwing error `Cannot resolve keyword 'parent_user' into field. Choices are: age, bio, gender,` anyway my problem is solved thanks :).